# AEM Components - Components inserted into "Drag Components here" box

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I just created a custom "progress bar" component. Adding the component in the Classic UI or Touch UI causes the component to be placed behind the "Drag components here" box. I thought that inserting components would cause the "Drag components here" box to shift down to make room for the new component.  Is there a property to add or event to trigger to make the "Drag Components here" box shift down?

Here is a screenshot of the issue.  The editBar is just above the top of the "Drag components or assets here" box.
[image]

Here is the HTML that is currently used for the component:

```
<div class="progress-bar component" style="clear:both;" data-sly-use.progress="progressbar.js" >
    <div class="numerator" style="width: ${progress.percentage @ context='styleToken'}%; height: inherit;">
        ${progress.percentage}%
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your component is floating. Clear the float by adding `clear:both;` to your component CSS and the drag components or assets should move down accordingly.

Comment: I just added the HTML that is used for the component to my post. I had already added the `clear: both` style to the progress bar.  Did you mean for me to add it as a separate CSS file?